# Bash Input Function

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a script that can run  `git clone` with a URL after the user pastes it.

So, what the user pastes should go in the place in the script with `##WHAT-GOES-HERE?##`

```
#!/bin/bash
git close ##WHAT-GOES-HERE?##
```

Comment: In the future, try to isolate only the code related to your specific question; see the documentation on building a [mcve]. There's no point to including all the stuff about color highlighting and/or success/failure counting in a question that's only about reading input.

Comment: (Also, please search for duplicates *before* you ask a new question).

Answer (score 2):

The `read` command should do the trick.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Input git repo: " repo
git clone "$repo"
```

Comment: thankyou that worked!

Comment: @Major, please avoid answering obviously-duplicate questions. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", particularly the bullet regarding questions which "have already been asked and answered many times before".